# How do I finish this probability question?

Tags: probability

A fair 4-sided is rolled 6 times. What is the probability that the total number of 1’s and
2’s in the first three rolls equals the total number of 3’s and 4’s in the last three rolls?

Here's what I've done:
$P\{X=i\}=1/4$ for all $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ hence $E[X]=(1+2+3+4)/4=5/2$, $E[X^2]=(1+4+9+16)/4=15/2$, $Var(X)=15/2-(5/2)^2=5/4$ and hence the standard deviation=$5^(1/2)/2$. How can I follow up on this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Wait... Why are you looking at the expected value and variance of each of the rolls?  If all the question is is what you were asked in the beginning then this is entirely unrelated unnecessary information.

Comment: It may help you to ignore the flavor of "dice" and look instead at the problem if it were a coin.  What is the probability that a coin who is flipped six times has the same number of heads in the first half of the flips as it has tails in the second half of the flips.

Comment: None of your calculations seem to have anything to do with the question.  We're not interested in average values, but in a specific probability.  Here's a hint.  The probability that there are $n$ $1$'a and $2$'s in the first $3$ rolls is equal to the probability that there are $n$ $3$'a and $4$'s in the last $3$ rolls.

Comment: As for an approach... consider conditioning on the number of heads in the first half.  The probability of zero heads in the first half is $\frac{1}{2^3}$.  Given that there were zero heads in the first half, the probability there were zero tails in the second half of the flips is $\frac{1}{2^3}$.  How about $1$ head in the first half?  Continue for the other values.  Can you see how to combine all of this information to complete the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think too complicated on this one. This can be solved only using 'basic' probability: You might want to simplify this to a 2 sided coin in either head or tails, as all the chances are equivalent to a half. You need to find the sum of the square of the probability of having zero, one, two or three heads, which is $\frac{1^2+3^2+3^2+1^2}{8^2} = \frac{5}{16}$